# How to return a header name based on a cell value? VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I created a log details sheet to track changes made in an excel spreadsheet, but my code is not returning the column/header name.

[image]

The column name should return the column where changes occurred. In this case, it would be employee status.

This is what my excel file looks like.

[image]

Here is my VBA Code

```
Dim lastRng

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If ActiveSheet.Name <> "logdetails" Then

        Application.EnableEvents = False
        
        Sheets("logdetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ActiveSheet.Name & "-" & Target.Address(0, 0)
        Sheets("logdetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = Target.Address
        Sheets("logdetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Value = lastRng
        Sheets("logdetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).Value = Target.Value
        Sheets("logdetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 4).Value = Environ("username")
        Sheets("logdetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 5).Value = Now
        Sheets("logdetails").Columns("A:H").AutoFit
        
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set lastRng = ActiveCell
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    lastRng = Target.Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the column name is located in row 1:

```
Dim colName As String
colName = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Target.Column)
Sheets("logdetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = colName
```

Answer (score 0):

### A Workbook Sheet Change: Logging Old and New (`Application.Undo`)

- This is a different approach that first writes the `Target` formulas (if no formula, it's equivalent to values) to an array, then uses `Application.Undo`, then writes the old `Target` values to another array, then writes back the new values and populates the log worksheet using the information from the arrays.
- It covers multiple cells when e.g. copy-pasting.
- It partially covers multi-ranges (discontinuous, incontiguous) i.e. you can only write to those by using VBA e.g. `Range("A1,C3").Value = "Test"`. But the issue is that in the case of using VBA, `Application.Undo` will not work so you cannot get the old data in the 3rd column. Even worse, it might work wrong e.g. if you have previously changed something in a worksheet that is not affected by the code (in this case, only the log worksheet).

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Const dName As String = "LogDetails"
    Const HeaderRow As Long = 1
    Const dcCount As Long = 6
    
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim sName As String: sName = Sh.Name
    If StrComp(sName, dName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim uName As String: uName = Environ("USERNAME")
    Dim tStamp As Date: tStamp = Now
    
    Dim aData: aData = GetCellAddresses(Target)
    Dim hData: hData = GetHeaders(Target, HeaderRow)
        
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = UBound(aData)
    
    Dim nJag(): nJag = GetMultiRangeFormulas(Target)
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim IsUndoClear As Boolean
    
    On Error Resume Next
        Application.Undo
        IsUndoClear = Err.Number = 0
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim oJag(): Dim arg As Range, a As Long
    
    If IsUndoClear Then
        
        oJag = GetMultiRangeFormulas(Target)
    
        For Each arg In Target.Areas
            a = a + 1
            arg.Value = nJag(a)
        Next arg
    
    End If
    
    Dim dData(): ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To dcCount)
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, dr As Long
    
    For a = 1 To UBound(nJag)
        For r = 1 To UBound(nJag(a), 1)
            For c = 1 To UBound(nJag(a), 2)
                dr = dr + 1
                dData(dr, 1) = dName & "-" & aData(dr)
                dData(dr, 2) = hData(dr)
                If IsUndoClear Then dData(dr, 3) = oJag(a)(r, c)
                dData(dr, 4) = nJag(a)(r, c)
                dData(dr, 5) = uName
                dData(dr, 6) = tStamp
            Next c
        Next r
    Next a
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = Sh.Parent.Sheets(dName)
    Dim dfcell As Range
    Set dfcell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfcell.Resize(drCount, dcCount)
    
    drg.Value = dData
    drg.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next
        If Not Application.EnableEvents Then Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```vb
Function GetHeaders( _
    ByVal mrg As Range, _
    Optional ByVal HeaderRow As Long = 1) _
As Variant

    Dim Data() As String: ReDim Data(1 To mrg.Cells.CountLarge)
    
    Dim mCell As Range, c As Long
    
    For Each mCell In mrg.Cells
        c = c + 1
        Data(c) = mCell.EntireColumn.Cells(HeaderRow).Value
    Next mCell
    
    GetHeaders = Data

End Function

Function GetCellAddresses( _
    ByVal mrg As Range) _
As Variant
    
    Dim Data() As String: ReDim Data(1 To mrg.Cells.CountLarge)
    
    Dim mCell As Range, c As Long
    
    For Each mCell In mrg.Cells
        c = c + 1
        Data(c) = mCell.Address(0, 0)
    Next mCell
    
    GetCellAddresses = Data

End Function

Function GetMultiRangeFormulas( _
    ByVal mrg As Range) _
As Variant
    Dim Jag(): ReDim Jag(1 To mrg.Areas.Count)
    Dim arg As Range, Data(), a As Long
    For Each arg In mrg.Areas
        a = a + 1
        Data = GetRangeFormulas(arg)
        Jag(a) = Data
    Next arg
    GetMultiRangeFormulas = Jag
End Function

Function GetRangeFormulas( _
    ByVal rg As Range) _
As Variant
    Dim Data()
    If rg.Rows.Count * rg.Columns.Count = 1 Then
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Formula
    Else
        Data = rg.Formula
    End If
    GetRangeFormulas = Data
End Function
```