# Passing a range of columns as a constant parameter

Tags: excel, vba, parameters, range

I am trying to pass a range of columns as a parameter for a function.

```
For sr = 1 To srCount 
    If IsEmpty(Data(sr, 4)) Then
        
        dr = dr + 1
        Data(dr, 4) = Data(sr, 1) 'instead of just the first column, a range of columns
        
    End If
Next sr
```

I thought I could define a range ("A:C") and pass its reference as a parameter, but VBA doesn't seem to accept anything but (references to) long variables/constants as parameters for the Data() function. What is the correct syntax for such a thing?

***Edited 01/26 for clarification:*** `Data` is an array. The goal is to copy a row of a range of columns based on the condition that another cell in that row is empty (`If IsEmpty(Data(sr, 4))`). E.g. if cell(7,4) is empty, then row 7 of columns A-C should be copied to another area of the worksheet (K2:M2). If (13,4) is empty, then row 13, columns A-C to K3-M3, and so on.

As per @Cameron's tip I used Collections to store the ranges instead.

```
Dim users As New Collection
Dim cell As Range

With Worksheets(2) 
    users.Add .Range("A:C"), "Users"    
    users.Add .Range("K:M"), "FinalList"

End With


For Each cell In users.Item("Users")
   For sr = 1 to srCount
    If IsEmpty(Data(sr, 4)) Then
        
        dr = dr + 1
        FinalList = Users

    End If
Next sr
   
Next
```

Despite the research I can't find how I can manipulate Collections for this objective. Once I have all the necessary values stored in FinalList, how can I copy them to the goal Range ("K:M")?

Comment: It's not really clear what the issue is here: methods can be declared with parameters of any type. How is your function `Data` declared?  From your previous post  - is `Data()` an array ?  If Yes then you can only pass in numeric indexes, one for each dimension.  Might help to explain the final outcome you're looking for: how should `Data(sr, 1:3)` (if such a thing were possible) be put into `Data(sr, 4)`?

Comment: Is `Data()` a function or a variable? You're using it like a variable. Either way could you show us the function, or how you declared your variable?

Comment: If you're trying to store ranges in an array, you can either store range addresses in a string array, or store the ranges in a collection.

Comment: Hard to help if we don't know what you're after. Try a little harder. I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75228531) recently, and under `Standard Module...` are 4 functions that all have a range argument (and return an array). Maybe it will help or at least help you to clarify your question. I mean, why would you think that you can't pass a string like `"A:C"` or a range like `Range("A:C")`?

Comment: @TimWilliams @ CameronCritchlow thank you both for the heads up regarding arrays and ranges!

Comment: @VBasic2008 I edited my post, I hope it makes more sense now. As soon as I get home I will check out your code from your other post carefully, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using a Single Array to Extract Matching Data

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    
    Const SRC_CRITERIA_COLUMN As Long = 4
    Const DST_WORKSHEET_ID As Variant = 2 ' using the tab name is preferable!
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "K2"
    ' The following could be calculated from the source variables.
    Const DST_COLUMNS_COUNT As Long = 3
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' whatever...
    
    Dim Data() ' ?
    Dim srCount As Long ' ?
    
    ' whatever...
    
    Dim sr As Long, dr As Long, c As Long
    
    ' Write the matching values to the top of the array
    ' When using a single array, the result needs to be in the top-left
    ' of the array. The data of interest is already left-most
    ' so there is no column offset.
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        If IsEmpty(Data(sr, SRC_CRITERIA_COLUMN)) Then
            dr = dr + 1
            For c = 1 To DST_COLUMNS_COUNT
                Data(dr, c) = Data(sr, c)
            Next c
        End If
    Next sr

    ' Reference the destination range.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(DST_WORKSHEET_ID)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL)
    ' Note how you're using just the 'dr' number of rows
    ' and 'DST_COLUMNS_COUNT' number of columns.
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(dr, DST_COLUMNS_COUNT)
    
    ' Write the result from the top-left of the array to the destination range.
    drg.Value = Data
    ' Clear below.
    drg.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - drg.Row - dr + 1).Offset(dr).ClearContents

    MsgBox "Data copied.", vbInformation

End Sub
```